# UITextField not receiving touch event

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have two textfields on screen but only second textfields not receiving touch events.I checked with background color and already setDelegate to self.First textfield working fine.I have created textfield programmatically.Here is my code :

```
txtMsg = [[UITextField alloc] init];
txtMsg.delegate = self;
txtMsg.placeholder = @"Type your message here..";
txtMsg.frame = CGRectMake(10, 190, 300, 40);
txtMsg.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txtMsg.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
txtMsg.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
txtMsg.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
txtMsg.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
txtMsg.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtMsg.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
[txtMsg setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
[self.view addSubview:txtMsg];
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: You are creating two textfields programmatically right?

Comment: Can you please write code with both textfield ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
yourTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```